# Is factoring of a product state unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-state

Suppose I have a product state of two qubits (i.e. a vector of size 4x1). Given it is separable (no entanglement), is this separation unique?

Comment: If you think of pure states as *rays* in the [complex projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space), then yes, the separation is unique, almost by definition. More formally, I think this is the observation that the [Segre embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding) $\mathbb{CP}^1\times \mathbb{CP}^1\to \mathbb{CP}^3$ is injective

Answer (score 1):

It's unique up to global phase.

$|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle = (i |0\rangle) \otimes (-i|0\rangle)$

I think the easiest way to prove it is to go in reverse: start by assuming the factors are same/different (up to global phase), then show that implies the tensor products are also same/different (up to global phase).